# Loading a .NET 4.0 beta2 assembly in PowerShell 2.0

Tags: powershell-2.0

I tried loading PresentationFramework.dll from [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) 4.0 beta2 in PowerShell v2.0. But it fails with the following error.

> PS C:\Windows\system32> [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.21006\WPF\PresentationF
>   ramework.dll")
>
> Exception calling "LoadFile" with "1" argument(s): "This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013101B)"
>   At line:1 char:32
>   + [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile <<<< ("C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.21006\WPF\PresentationFramework.dll")
>      + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

How can I load this DLL file within PowerShell 2.0?

Comment: Why can't you load the 3.0 assembly instead?

Comment: Similar question is addressed in [launch powershell under .NET 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094694/launch-powershell-under-net-4)

Comment: possible duplicate of [launch powershell under .NET 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094694/launch-powershell-under-net-4)

Answer (score 0):

You can't load it. PowerShell is using the .NET 2.0 CLR, and 4.0 DLL files cannot be loaded.

It might be possible to reconfigure PowerShell to run in the newer CLR or host PowerShell in a .NET 4.0 application, but I wouldn't recommend either of those.

Comment: oh thanks for the commentless downvote, that was helpful :-) Can anyone point out if I'm wrong in my assumption?

Answer (score 0):

Run this code in the administrative mode of [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell):

```
reg add hklm\software\microsoft\.netframework /v OnlyUseLatestCLR /t REG_DWORD /d 1
reg add hklm\software\wow6432node\microsoft\.netframework /v OnlyUseLatestCLR /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue on Windows Server 2008 (with PowerShell v2) and I resolved by installing these 2 updates :

Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 
https://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/download/details.aspx?id=40779

PowerShell v4
https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=40855